# Get the total distance a car covers per day

Tags: c#, sql-server, timestamp, console-application, distance

I want to calculate the distance a car cover each day for a month. I have the coordinates for the car starting point, and I have few other coordinates locations . Anytime the car crosses this location it is registered in the database. The car can register in a location once per day. The car can pass at one location many times but is counted only once.

Ex. The car is registered at location A, so the distance from Home->A->Home is calculated. If it is registered at point A and B then the distance HOME->A->B->Home. Note : The order does not matter it can be HOME->B->A->Home

In my database I have:

```
Car : CarId, StartPoint;
Registration: id, CarId, checkpointId, timestamp;
Checkpoint: checkpointId, Coordinates.
```

I use GeoLocation to calculate the distance between two points. But I have no Idea how to check for the distance per one day only and how to make the function for the calculation calculate 2 to multiple points.

I need SQL or C# guidance.

Comment: You have a timestamp.  So, you know what points happen on what day.  Start small, just try and get all of the registrations for a given day.  Then once you have that, try and compute the total distance.

Comment: Well I will try that.

Comment: Are you looking for "As the crow flies" distance or the actual mileage a car would travel?

Comment: so if a car drives from town a to town b and then back to town a, are you counting just the distance between a and b or the full round trip?

Comment: What happens when you go Home>A>B>A>Home since A is only registered once (from your description) how does it catch the return leg of the trip correctly?

Comment: I have coordinates of the points so I just calculate the distance. If it goes Home>A>B>A> the distance I will calculate will be Home >A>B>HOME.